# Failed to compile lua in windows phone 8 system

Tags: windows-phone-8, lua, cocos2d-x

We are working on IOS and Android with cocos2dx， we have lots of lua script in our codes, and it working well in the IOS and Android. now we plan porting the app to Windows Phone 8 or Windows RT.

But we get stuck by compiling lua in windows phone 8 system. It looks as if lua depends on some win32 API which are not supported in windows phone system.

The compilation errors are:

> undeclared identifier 'LoadLibraryA'
>
> undeclared identifier 'GetModuleNameA'

So, anyone has some ideas?

Comment: What build errors do you encounter when you try to compile on that platform? Add it to your question.

Comment: @greatwolf the compilation errors have been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the first non-comment line in the Makefile to `PLAT=generic`, lua will compile without shared library support (that means you will not be able to load `.dll` with the `require` command) and lua will compile without any link errors. If you need to use C-libraries then add them statically to the lua binary by adding them to the `preloadedlibs` array in `linit.c`

Comment: The recommended way to include static libraries is to add them to `linit.c` and rebuild.

Comment: Thank you I'll add that to my answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, @hogliux, I have compiled lua in wp8 system successfully.

Comment: @Bloodwolf: Is it possible to get the project files for the WP8 version of Lua? Did you do it with VS?

Comment: Yes, I compiled lua with VS. @user1829325